# struck with raintrap in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

```
a = [3,0,0,2,0,4]       #input
l = []                  #left side 
r = []                  #right side
sum = 0                 #output
l[0] = a[0]             #loading a[0] into l[0]
for i in range(len(a)):     #finding left tallest
   l[i] = max(a[i],l[i-1])  #finding maximum and adding into left list
r[n-1] = a[n-1]             # loading the elements from last into right list 
for i in range(len(n-2)):   #finding right tallest
   r[i] = max(a[i],l[i+1])  #finding maximum and adding into right list
for i in range(0,len(n)):       
   sum = sum + (min(l[i],r[i])-a[i]*1)      #sum of inputs
print(sum)
```

Expecting the output sum = 10
3x2 + 1x1 + 1x3 = 10

updated code for the previous one.

```
def findwater(a,n):                     
left = [0]*n                    
right = [0]*n                   
sum = 0                 
left[0] = a[0]          
for i in range(1,n):    
    left[i] = max(left[i-1],a[i])   
right[n-1] = a[n-1]
for i in range((n-2),-1,-1):    
    right[i] = max(right[i+1],a[i])
for i in range(0,n):        
    sum = sum + (min(left[i],right[i])-a[i]*1)      
return sum

a = [3,0,0,2,0,4]   
n = len(a)
print(findwater(a,n))
```

This time I'm getting this error  **left[i] = max(left[i-1],a[i])
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**  Help me to correct my code.

Comment: On what line are you getting the error? Can you try to make your example smaller?

Comment: You seem to have multiple problems with your code. For example: what is `n`?

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name, as it is a built in function

Comment: @Moberg I'm getting this error l[0] = a[0]. I know i'm wrong so many times in the program.

Comment: @ZakirHussain Asking for an item in an empty list is what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code.

1. Variable names could be more informative `l` -> `left_side`. This way you don't need to have a comment on every line.
2. You use a variable `n` that is not initialized to anything.
3. Perhaps split your code into multiple functions. Then you can investigate if each function does what it should.

The first problem at hand is on line 5. You do `l[0] = ...` The problem is `l` is an empty list, so you can't access element [0], that is why you get the error.

Instead you could append an element to l:

```
l.append(a[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Line 8 : `r[n-1] = a[n-1]`, r length is 0 and n is uninitialized so I think your error is probably here.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: That is one of many problems, but not the error that is mentioned in the question.